# Sizeof pointer in structure in C

Tags: c, struct

I have such structure:

```
struct node{
    int key;
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Then I created `link`:

```
struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
link->key = 10;
link->data = 100;
link->next = link;
```

When I want to find out the size of each element I do:

```
printf("%zd %zd %zd %zd\n", sizeof(link->key), sizeof(link->data), sizeof(link->next), sizeof(link));
```

And as output I have:

```
4 4 8 8
```

So, the first question is why `sizeof(link)` doesn't include `sizeof(link->next)`?

The second question is:
When I try to `free` allocated memory of `link`:

```
printf("Size of link is %zd\n", sizeof(link));
free(link);
printf("Now size of link is %zd\n", sizeof(link));
```

I have:

```
Size of link is 8
Now size of link is 8
```

Why didn't freeing of memory happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, the first question is why `sizeof(link)` doesn't include `sizeof(link->next)`?

Because `link` is a pointer. If you print `sizeof(*link)`, you would [get a different number](http://ideone.com/DcVcTY).

> Why didn't freeing of memory happen?

Freeing memory does happen. It's just that it cannot be measured the way that you try it, i.e. with `sizeof`. The size remains the same regardless of whether the pointer points to something valid or to something invalid.